# how to set tooltip hide when scrolled

Tags: tooltip

I have a checkbox to which I am displaying a tooltip when you mouse hover it.
However the toolip is displayed on the fore ground when mouse is scrolled.
How can we hide when the component goes background.

```
<td class="text-right">
     <input type="checkbox" id="temp" formControlName="temp" 
        name="tempfld"
        tooltip="This is tooltip" />
</td>
```

Comment: what library are you using for the tooltip ?

Comment: library? what you do mean by library

Comment: there is  no such attribute in html as tooltip use title

Comment: so are you using bootstrap or something else for the tooltip ?

Comment: I am using bootstrap

Comment: which version of bootstrap ?

Comment: oops, I am using ng2-tooltip library

Answer (score 0):

use `ng2-tooltip-directive`, as `ng2-tooltip` is depricated

```
npm i ng2-tooltip-directive
```

Options can be set in the directive tag, so they have the highest priority.

```
<td class="text-right">
     <input type="checkbox" id="temp" formControlName="temp" 
        name="tempfld"
        placement="top" show-delay="500"
        tooltip="This is tooltip" />
</td>
```

You may pass as an object:

```
<td class="text-right">
     <input type="checkbox" id="temp" formControlName="temp" 
        name="tempfld"
        tooltip="This is tooltip"
        [options]="myOptions" />
</td>

myOptions = {
    'placement': 'left',
    'show-delay': 500
}
```